# Sum of reciprocals of rapidly increasing series is irrational.

Tags: number-theory

$$\text{Show that if the integers } 1 < b_1 <b_2 ... \text{ increase so rapidly that } $$
$$\frac{1}{b_{k+1}} +\frac{1}{b_{k+2}} +... < \frac{1}{b_k -1} - \frac{1}{b_k} ,\text{ for } k \geq 1  $$
$$ \text{then the number } \sum b_k^{-1} \text{ is irrational.} \\ 
\text{Prove that }\sum_0^{\infty}(2^{3^k}+1)^{-1} \text{ is irrational.}$$
(Fundamentals of Number Theory, LeVeque, 6.3.4 (b))

As this problem appears after the problem about Egyptian expansion of rational number in the book, I tried to make connection but it seems it isn't easy to do that.
Is there any good idea to handle this? I've looked through some previous questions about harmonic sum of rapidly increasing sequence being an irrational number but I couldn't get idea for this problem.

Also I checked [the identical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84796/irrationality-of-two-series?rq=1) but it didn't help much.

Comment: Can you relate the condition to the Egyptian fraction expansion that the greedy algorithm produces?

Comment: Oh I think I got it. So the point was that one can build next term of Egyptian expansion recursively from previous term and this process doesn't end, resulting irrationality of the sum.